If weights and biases are in superposition state, do we still need backpropagation algorithm?
Deep learning is basically finding the best weights and biases in order to reduce loss that is computed by the defined loss function to be as small as possible (global minimum).
Finding the global minimum was not an easy task, and it seems there is no algorithm yet to check whether current weights and biases are in the global minimum or local minimum for all possibilities of weights and biases.
Gradient descent basically returns an output of reference for the weights and biases to tune their values. Hence, it's possible that the model will be stuck in local minima due to the optimizer thinking there's already a global minimum (while it's not).
But what if we set the weights and biases value in superposition state with a quantum computer?
That's to say we will always reach global minimum by computing loss function output in superposition state due to the consequence of superposition state at weights and biases.
Does it mean we don't need gradient descent anymore?
In another word, the weight initialization in superposition state and n-times measurement observed are considered learning processes.
